# Are there any languages that have both high- and low-level facilities?

Tags: programming-languages, language-design, language-features, low-level, high-level

Are there any languages that have both high- and low-level facilities? If not, is it feasible to create one? Why or why not?

In theory, it would be very helpful to have a programming language that has both shell and regular programming language facilities, like [Forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29) for example can easily be made to, and also to have high-level facilities; Forth does not seem (and it would probably take a good bit of work to make it) like a natural fit for high-level things.

Of course, languages like C or C++ can be made to simulate features of high-level languages, but at the cost of ugly or difficult syntax, and the addition of considerably more complexity, or at the cost of a lot of work, which would be unnecessary since it would often be easier just to use a more standard high-level programming language.

**Clarification**: Low-level meaning things like manual memory management, limited data structures, only one return value, and the like. Examples: [Assembly language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language), C, C++ to some extent, and Forth.

High-level language examples would be: Python, [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl), JavaScript, Java and C# to a big extent, [Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29).

Comment: C++ _is_ a high level language.

Comment: Errr...  Forth, C, and C++ are all high-level languages.  Low-level languages consist of machine code and assembly languages. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-level_programming_language

Comment: @MatthewFlynn:  High-level and low-level are *relative* terms.  When used as if they were absolute terms, they are implicitly comparing a language to other contemporary languages.  C was a high-level language by the standards of 30 years ago.  By today's standards it's low-level, since people use higher level languages for day-to-day programming now.

Comment: I still don't see how C++ fits your definition of low level, apart from having manual memory management (which can be greatly alleviated with smart pointers).

Comment: @dsimcha: I'm sorry, the term "low-level programming language" is well-defined as "In computer science, a low-level programming language is a programming language that provides little or no abstraction from a computer's instruction set architecture."  It refers to first- and second-generation languages.  C, with its structs, functions, and procedures provide high-level abstraction.  Is C OOP?  Heck no. 

I might point out that most of the 4GLs that were "higher level" than C++, Python, and Java died with little fanfare in the late 90s.

Comment: @DavidBrown Pointers -> low level, is the answer I get when I ask the same question...

Comment: @MatthewFlynn It's quite funny that you are quoting the Wikipedia article that [later on mentions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-level_programming_language#Relative_meaning): `The terms high-level and low-level are inherently relative. Some decades ago, the C language, and similar languages, were most often considered "high-level" Many programmers today might refer to C as low-level.` which is exactly what @dsimcha wrote...

Comment: @DavidBrown:  C++ isn't low level but it lacks some of the ability to do metaprogramming that a truly high level language would have.  Imagine trying to re-implement Boost, with all its crazy template hacks, in D or Python or some higher level language that's actually designed for metaprogramming.

Comment: @Abafei -1 Your clarification doesn't really make sense. You can't impose your own interpretations of what languages are low-level and what are high-level. If you are looking for a language that combines specific characteristics and features, that's a different question and you'll have to tell us what those are _exactly_, but you can't really tell us what low and high level means, just to bypass the terms's relative meanings. Please use terminology appropriately.

Comment: Calling Java and C# high level to C++'s low level is hilarious. In a bad way.

Comment: C++ is a lower level language (lower than Lisp/Perl/Forth/etc.) indeed, since it provides no functionality for hiding low level features (i.e., it forces leaky abstractions), and there is a hard abstraction level cap which is not possible to break through. Forth is different - it is a decent meta-language, allowing building an unlimited number of abstraction layers.

Comment: If C is lower level, I don't see what's wrong with describing C++ as being lower level but with a big giant robot arm bolted on to it.

Comment: This question is closed, but [Factor](http://www.factorcode.org/) is a high-level language which can be used at (C)sea level: for example [mmap](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/vocab-io.mmap.html); [malloc](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/word-malloc,libc.html)

Comment: D fits the bill.

Answer (score 16):

C++ is the canonical example of a language that combines low-level and high-level features<sup>1</sup>. It doesn't simulate anything, it provides native support for almost every high-level construct you'll usually find in a common high-level language and almost every low-level construct you'll find in C.

But of course the terms are highly relative, there was a point in time (not that long ago<sup>2</sup>) where C was considered a very high level language. And there are quite a few other languages that offer considerable low-level functionalities while still commonly regarded as high-level, and vice versa, the lines are kind of fuzzy.

As for the syntax, that's something that naturally affected by the language's level of abstraction. [Low-level generally means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-level_programming_language):

> In computer science, a low-level programming language is a programming language that provides little or no abstraction from a computer's instruction set architecture. Generally this refers to either machine code or assembly language. The word "low" refers to the small or nonexistent amount of abstraction between the language and machine language; because of this, low-level languages are sometimes described as being "close to the hardware."

So naturally a low-level language adopts a syntax that's closer to machine code, which is inherently non human friendly. Quite a few languages, like C++, have adopted a wide variety of [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar), as a mechanism to make things easier to read or to express. But syntactic sugar is something that almost every high level language has opted for, C++'s sugar alone doesn't make it a low-level language.

As for the complexity of a low & high-level language, it's also natural: It's a tool with multiple goals, every single goal adds to its complexity. That's unavoidable regardless of the goal. High-level languages are not "better" than low-level one, they are just more concentrated on one goal. Languages that are designed with ease of use as a primary goal tend to be high-level, but that's only important if the necessary trade-offs to achieve the goal don't affect your applications.

Low or high level doesn't really matter, languages are primarily tools. You should choose the one that best fits whatever you're building in combination with what skills you have. Most popular languages are [multi-purpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_programming_language) and [Turing complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness), in theory they are valid choices for building almost anything. There are no absolutes, of course, you may win in some areas if you opt for a high-level language and in others if you opt for a lower-level one, even within the same application.

Most large scale applications mix and match, following the "right tool for the job" mentality, and that's a more efficient approach, imho, than trying to have your cake and eat it too.

<sub><sup>1</sup> But please note that there isn't a definitive answer on what's considered a strictly high-level feature and what a low-level one.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> In human years, in software years it was long ago...</sub>

Comment: +1: Calling Java and C# high level and C++ low level is laughable.

Comment: C++ does not provide many of the proper high level languages constructs. It does not provide a usable functionality for extending the language, it does not allow hiding the low level aspects of the language. It does not even contain a proper pattern matching, the most common feature of the modern high level languages. So it is indeed a much lower level language than most of those currently defined as high level. But I'd back DeadMG, it is dead funny to call C++, a language with at least some metaprogramming capabilities a lower level one to Java, which is not extendable at all.

Comment: Despide not agreeing at all on calling C++ a high level language, +1 for renaming a lame, idiotic term "general-purpose language" to a much more correct "multi-purpose".

Comment: @SK-logic The problem is with what's considered `proper high level languages constructs`. If this is my opinion vs yours, there isn't any point in discussing it further, we can just agree to disagree. But if you have some kind of reference, I'd love to see it. I think it'd be saner to approach the terms either historically (C++ currently is not considered a very high level language) or strictly in comparing two languages (Python is higher level than C++), and always loosely. But again if there are references I don't know about, please share.

Comment: @Yannis Rizos, for me the division between clearly low-level languages and high level languages is in the ability to hide any of the lower level (no matter what level it is) constructs from the higher levels of abstraction. You can't do it with C++ - there will always be functions, classes, methods, variables, types, etc. You can't hide any of that low level concepts. In the true high level languages, even as trivial and basic as Forth, any such constructs can be abstracted out. So, presence of the leaky abstraction is a clean barrier.

Comment: @SK-logic I get it, I've read you comment on the question. But I once battled with assembly (lost that fight), since then everything else is high level to me. I'm not suggesting that the leaky abstraction barrier is not a sensible one, I won't go there. What I'm saying is that for relative and subjective terms every opinion is equally valid, and since there isn't a hard limit on how high we can go, what's considered high level changes considerably over time.

Comment: @YannisRizos, of course it is only a matter of terminology. I just think that my definition is the most practical one, since there are several useful implications out of it. Other definitions are purely theoretical. As for tackling the abstraction, I'm often dealing with an assembler - but I have not written any code in it manually for a very long time. I'm rather generating the code using very high level declarative specifications (e.g., with Coq). I think that's exactly what the low level languages are for: they have to be compilation targets, they're not for humans.

Comment: @SK-logic:  Having done some Forth in the past, what aspects do you think are higher-level?  Forth is firmly based on the stack, which isn't going to be abstracted out, and the `word`.  In what way is the stack a higher-level concept than the class?  I'm failing to understand what you mean.

Comment: It compiles directly to machine code right? Doesn't that make it lowER than Java -> bytecode -> VM runtime or Source -> CLI to ? to profit or whatever the hell it is that happens in .NET languages?

Answer (score 6):

C++ fits the bill to some extent if you use the right template metaprogramming tricks.  [D](http://www.dlang.org) takes this to the next level.  D has every low-level facility that C has except the macro preprocessor (which is made obsolete by a combination of a real module system and [string mixins](http://d-programming-language.org/statement.html#MixinStatement)) and bitfields (which are implemented in the standard library instead).

On the high-level side, D is garbage collected, *but the garbage collector is written in D and manual memory management can be done using C's malloc and free*.  The template metaprogramming system was designed with the help of Andrei Alexandrescu, the author of *Modern C++ Design* and is actually designed for *readable* metaprogramming beyond simple generics.  It is advanced enough to allow high-level standard library modules like [std.range](http://d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_range.html), [std.algorithm](http://d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html) and [std.parallelism](http://d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_parallelism.html).

Pushing the boundaries even further, I mentored a Google Summer of Code project last summer to create a matrix library in D.  It's not production ready yet, but it allows matrix expressions to be written in a high-level form like the following, with the language inferring all the types and no unnecessary temporary matrices/vectors allocated:

```
auto m = matrix(
    [[1.0, 2, 3],
     [4.0, 5, 6],
     [7.0, 8, 9]]
);

auto v1 = vector([8.0, 6, 7]);
auto v2 = vector([3.0, 1, 4]);
auto v3 = vector([2.0, 7, 1]);

// .t is the transpose operator.
auto result = eval( inv(m * v1 * v2.t) * v3 );
writeln(result.pretty);
```

I doubt even Matlab code would be much shorter or cleaner than that, and matrices are Matlab's home turf.